# What is the best way to use a secrets package, if previously I used a random package to generate unique_code in python?

Tags: python, random

i have this code for generate unique_code

**using Random Package**

```
import random

FullChar = 'CDHKPMQRVXY123456789'
total = 20
count = 7

for i in range(total):
        select = random.sample(FullChar, count)
        random.shuffle(select)
        unique_code = ''.join(select)
        print(entries)
```

**I Tried Using Secrets Package**

```
import random

FullChar = 'CDHKPMQRVXY123456789'
total = 20
count = 7

for i in range(total):
        select = random.sample(FullChar, count)
        select = secrets.SystemRandom.sample(FullChar, count)
        secrets.SystemRandom.shuffle(select)
        unique_code = ''.join(select)
```

Here I use random package to generate unique_code(import random), but I think this is the old way to generate unique_code with this package, I want to use secrets package to generate unique_code(import secrets). What is the best way to use a secret package(import secrets), if previously I used a random package to generate unique_code like the code I wrote earlier?

When I used Random Package it's Clear, but when i changes it to secret package it's showing error

```
    select = secrets.SystemRandom.sample(FullChar, count)
TypeError: sample() missing 1 required positional argument: 'k'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's just try:

```
$ python3
Python 3.9.6 (default, Jul 16 2021, 00:00:00) 
>>> 
>>> import secrets
>>> count=5
>>> xs = list(range(20))
>>> 
>>> sel1 = secrets.SystemRandom.sample(xs, count)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sample() missing 1 required positional argument: 'k'
>>>
```

Problem reproduced. But as long as the number of positional parameters is wrong, Python probably won't bother to complain about anything else. So let's just provide *any* extra positional parameter:

```
>>> 
>>> import math
>>> 
>>> sel1 = secrets.SystemRandom.sample(math.pi, xs, count)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/random.py", line 447, in sample
    randbelow = self._randbelow
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute '_randbelow'
>>>
```

Hence, judging from the request for some *_randbelow* attribute, Python requires the *first* positional parameter to be a generator.  Let's just provide one:

```
>>> 
>>> gen = secrets.SystemRandom()
>>> 
>>> sel1 = secrets.SystemRandom.sample(gen, xs, count)
>>> 
>>> sel1
[13, 16, 3, 15, 0]
>>> 
>>> gen.shuffle(sel1)
>>> 
>>> sel1
[15, 16, 3, 0, 13]
>>>
```

So it looks OK now.

**Note:** in retrospect, it seems a bit obvious. If you want some random subset, and you have provided both the whole set and the count of elements you want, what could possibly be still missing ? if not a random number generator.

Answer (score 0):

jpmariner sort of got there, but it is by using the object system weirdly.  You just need to call the method on the object, something like:

```
from secrets import SystemRandom
# or alternatively
# from random import SystemRandom

full_char = 'CDHKPMQRVXY123456789'
count = 7

rng = SystemRandom()

for _ in range(20):
    letters = rng.choices(full_char, k=count)
    rng.shuffle(letters)
    print(''.join(letters)
```

will print out 20 passwords.  I've made the following change: using `choices` to sample "[with replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_sample)" which is the right thing to do for stronger passwords (this makes it more difficult for an attacker)

Note: `SystemRandom` is defined in the `random` module and is just re-exported by the `secrets` module, however importing it from `secrets` might emphasize why it's being used.  Where ever you import it from all randomness comes from the system's CSPRNG, so is suitable for cryptographic purposes.

Comment: ok i see, so random and secret have similar function, right?

Comment: @here yes, here they provide the same functionality.  I've had a bit of a think and reworded my answer to reflect my understanding.  [PEP 506](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0506/) is interesting reading here!